# Bit Setting and Bit Shifting in Ansi C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, ansi-c

Can anyone explain this bitwise operation syntax?

```
#define Bitset(var,bitno) ((var) |=1UL<<(bitno))
```

I know it sets the bits of `var`, but I can't understand the syntax.

Comment: The syntax consists of completely unremarkable C operators. Nothing unusual about it. What exactly do you want explained? If you don't know the meaning of basic C operators, it is something you can read in a *book*. This is not the place for "explain the general expression syntax in C" questions. If you have a problem understanding something specific, then you have to say what it is.

Comment: It's a macro.  Replace the macro name "Bitset" with the characters that follow, substituting the macro's positional parameters for "var" and "bitno".  Strip away the unnecessary parens to understand it better.

Comment: You might be thrown by the rarely-used "1UL", which is just the literal 1 in unsigned long form.

Comment: Thanks! It was 1UL that actually messed me up. I just moved to embedded C from ASM and things look scary sometimes.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's break it down, piece by piece:

`1UL` is an `unsigned long int` with a value of 1 represented at the bit level as:

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

the `<<` is a "bit shift" operator which will move all the bits in that value above to the left `bitno` number of times.  If it's `1UL<<5`, you'll end up with:

```
00000000000000000000000000100000
```

Once you have this value, the `|=` (which is a [bitwise OR operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) with an assignment) will essentially force the bit of `var` that's in line with that `1` to be a `1` and wont touch any other bits because (`X | 0 = X`)

Lets say `var` is `37` and `bitno` is `7`.  Then everything at the bit level will look like this:

```
00000000000000000000000000100101  // var
00000000000000000000000010000000  // 1UL<<7

00000000000000000000000010100101  // var | (1UL<<7)
```

Finally, in case it isn't clear, the `#define` marks `Bitset` as a [function-like macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion).

Answer (score 5):

This is a macro. Whenever the preprocessor hits a statement like `Bitset(var,bitno)` it faithfully replaces it with

```
var = var | 1UL << (bitno)
```

Further to explain this.

**UL** here means **Unsigned Long**.

Operator `|` is used for `bitwise OR` operation. so the variable `var` is `OR`ed with
 `1UL << bitno` and assigned back to `var`

Then during **runtime** or **compile time** depending on the nature of the program,

Say `var` is `01000110` 
and `bitno` is `5`

then `1UL << 5 = 32` or `00100000`

then

```
var = 01000110 | 00100000
```

ie `var = 01100110`

Comment: @nico I am just competing with others.

Comment: didn't know it was a competition

Comment: @nico People answer so quick.  like u commented on me. .\

Comment: still downvoted even when valid. probably a metaSO question   :P

Comment: This was downvoted because its first iteration did nothing to answer the question.  Now that it's edited and fixed, I doubt whoever downvoted will come back.  Next time, instead, try to type out a complete answer before submitting it and then take the time to clean it up. The later your response, the further towards the top it will show so don't feel pressure to "compete".

Answer (score 1):

Say var=8, that is `0000 1000` in binary.

If you do

`8 | 16` you will have `0000 1000 | 0001 0000` which will give you `0001 1000`, because the `|` operator sets the bit if either bit is 1.

So you are applying the `|` operator to your value and `1<<n`, that is to `0000 0001` shifted of n bits to the left.

For instance `1 << 3` is `0000 0001 << 2 = 0000 0100`.

In essence: doing `Bitset(8,3)` will generate a mask with only the third bit set by doing `1 << 3`, getting `0000 0100`.
It will then "or" this mask to 8, giving: `0000 1000 | 0000 0100`, resulting in `0000 1100`, that is, you set the 3rd bit of 8.